# Set different aspect/action at runtime for selected state in UITableViewCell in Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have a storyboard with several UITableView. I would like to select a different display type of selected state for UITableViewCell. I explain better.

Going straight to the code I would like to have an enum or flag which drive the type of highlight.

```
-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
     switch(cellViewMode) {
       case Simple:
         [self simpleCell:selected];
         break;

       case Full:
         [self fullCell:selected];
         break;

       default:
         // default method...
         break; 
    }
}
```

I am looking for the best way to set this cellViewMode flag once and never to be changed, based on the view controller type, considering that actually I am calling my cell in the usual recommended way for storyboard, where the identifier is declared in it, rather than before when there was a static NSString *cellIdentifier in cellForRow: and an if checking the cell existence:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Obj *obj = // get obj from datasource
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyTableCellIdentifier]; // <-- this is how it is done in storyboard
    cell.cellTitle.text=obj.titleForCell;
    cell.cellDescr.text=obj.descriptionForCell;

    return cell;
}
```

I have specified that I need a flag, but I am open to other solutions, like categories, or whatever may works nice and in elegant way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After little research, I easily solve this by using the cell identifier property, but using 'if' statement because of the nature of identifier.

```
-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
     if(self.reuseIdentifier==SimpleConstant) {
         [self simpleCell:selected];
         return;
     }

     if(self.reuseIdentifier==FullConstant) {
         [self fullCell:selected];
         return;
     }

     // handle other default case...
}
```

personally I don't like 'if' statement used like this, but I didn't fine a better solution.